# SQL Server : designer incompatible generate script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, ssms

We have a SQL Server 2012 for our test box, and a SQL Server 2005 for our production box. Recently, we moved to automated deployment scripts which execute SQL scripts as part of our deployment process.

We encountered an issue whereby the script generated by SSMS, using "Generate Script" in the designer, outputs a script that was incompatible with SQL Server 2005. It added statement SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE) which is SQL Server 2008+

We have tried changing the compatibility of the database to SQL Server 2005 but this did not resolve the issue. Interestingly, when using  Script Table As > Create To > New Query Window, this statement is not included.

There is a SSMS setting "Match script settings to source = false", but, this requires you to set a SQL Server Version globally, which is not an option for us as we maintain a variety of SQL Server versions. Is there a way we can downgrade the "Generate Scripts" compatibility?

Comment: Can't you upgrade your prod box? 2005 is ancient history, out of support for years. You really should not be running live code on something like that. Better to run both environments on the same version anyway so you don't get unexpected issues when you deploy to production.

Comment: You *really* need to upgrade. It's not just that SQL Server 2005 went out of support almost a decade ago. Test results on 2012 or even 2008 won't apply to 2005. Even SQL Server 2012 is out of support anyway, the earliest supported version is 2016. And since 2016, the Developer edition is free and previously Enterprise features like partitioning, columnstores and compression are available for all editions, even Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the "Generate Scripts" task in SSMS, you can define what server version to create the script for:

[image]

That should ensure no commands or options are used which are not present in SQL Server 2005.

But I second @ADyson's sentiment - SQL Server **2005** is beyond dead and buried and it's a risk to run production code on such an old version of SQL Server ......  you **really should upgrade** to a more recent version ASAP!